# convert dataframe in html table for e-mail

Tags: r

I have a code which gives below mentioned output.

Output:

```
   df count  count2   percentage
1  A   100      0        0.0
2  B    80     20       20.0
3  C    50     30       37.5
4  D    25     25       50.0
```

Now i want to convert this dataframe in html table so that i can set this through e-mail in e-mail body.

I am using library(htmlTable) but couldn't do it yet.

Desired output as html table:

```
_________________________________________
               19/01/2017
("Write comments.......................")
_________________________________________

         df count  count2   percentage
      1  A   100      0        0.0
      2  B    80     20       20.0
      3  C    50     30       37.5
      4  D    25     25       50.0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's something to get you started,

```
df <- structure(list(df = structure(1:4, .Label = c("A", "B", "C", 
"D"), class = "factor"), count = c(100L, 80L, 50L, 25L), count2 = c(0L, 
20L, 30L, 25L), percentage = c(0, 20, 37.5, 50)), .Names = c("df", 
"count", "count2", "percentage"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4"))

# install.packages(c("htmlTable"), dependencies = TRUE)
library(htmlTable)

htmlTable(df,  
          ctable=c("double"),
          caption="19/01/2017, ('Write comments....................... ')")
```

yield,

[image: d]

from there you can [look in the manual](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/htmlTable/vignettes/general.html) to adjust decimal places, centering and other details.

Comment: How can i add one more line on caption and give space in caption between date and comment section.

Comment: did you study the examples I liked to? It's generally good to demonstrate you already put some effort into it before you ask questions.

Comment: Yes Eric, i studied the examples shared by you and based on that i have done some modifications in the table, but i couldn't find the way to add line on caption. and for spacing i have tried caption=paste(sys.date,"       comment") but it didn't work.

Comment: Time to start reading [the `htmlTable` manual PDF](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/htmlTable/htmlTable.pdf). Start by reading about `txtMergeLines` on p. 20. Why did you use `sys.time`  and not `Sys.Date()`? What manual told you do do so?

Comment: I have used Sys.Date(), which function i need to refere to add line.

Comment: Please write your questions and comments out in full sentences. I do not understand what you are saying. Are you are making a point, clarifying a point, or asking a new question? I will also recommend to take a look at the [how do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163542/discussion-between-eric-fail-and-user9211845).